# View rooted objects in WinDbg

Tags: windbg, sos

I am trying to investigate what looks like a memory leak in .NET using WinDbg.

However, when I try to examine output of `!dumpheap -type` I see that many, if not all objects listed are "Free" objects.  I'd like to filter the list to see if there any that are rooted (have references to them).

I tried the following script:

```
.foreach (t {!dumpheap -mt 0000000091ea94f0 -short}) { .if(!gcroot ${t}) { !mdt ${t} } }
```

However, it does not output anything.  Is there a way to filter out the output of `!dumpheap` to show only rooted objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Free "objects"

.NET uses a heap manager to keep track of memory. This makes it possible to allocate objects smaller than 64 kB, where 64 kB is the minimum memory the OS provides.

So, .NET gets at least 64 kB and then splits that into smaller pieces. Those pieces which are unused can be understood as objects of type `Free`.

To get a better overview of `Free` objects, use `!dumpheap -stat -type Free`. Those `Free` objects don't have a root, because they are not actually objects.

But you can also see a whole lot of other objects including the sum of their sizes. Those are likely rooted.

### Rooted objects

Unfortunately, commands like `!gcroot` don't have a boolean return value, so you need to use some tricky stuff. The basic `.foreach` loop is already quite good.

To get a comparable return value, we'll use the root count number, which is `1` in the following case:

```
0:004> !gcroot 02701078
HandleTable:
    001f11ec (strong handle)
    -> 02701078 System.OutOfMemoryException

Found 1 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
```

Since the number can be 1, 2, 3 etc., it seems more reliable to check for `!=0`. Let's start like this:

```
.shell -ci"!gcroot ${t}" find "Found 0"
```

This will only keep the one line "Found 0 unique roots ...", otherwise nothing at all.

Then let's minimize the output just to keep the number by skipping the first word ("Found") using `/pS 1`, then processing one word and then skipping the rest (actually a maximum of 99 words) using `/ps 99`:

```
.foreach /pS 1 /ps 99(word {.shell -ci"!gcroot ${t}" find "Found 0"}) {.echo ${word}}
```

This will leave us with `0` only.

Next, use can use `$scmp()` to compare the string:

```
.if ($scmp("${word}","0")==0) {.echo nothing} .else {.echo something}
```

The whole script (formatted for readability, remove the line breaks and indentation):

```
.foreach (t {!dumpheap -short -mt 70c240b4}) { 
    .foreach /pS 1 /ps 99 (word {.shell -ci"!gcroot ${t}" find "Found 0"}) {
        .if ($scmp("${word}","0")==0){
            .echo nothing
        } .else {
            .echo something
        }
     }
 }
```

In your case, replace `.echo something` by `!mdt ${t}`.

### PyKd

Since above script is hard to understand and error-prone, you might want to try PyKD. Look for `dbgCommand()` to execute debugger commands and get the result as a string. You can then operate on that string with any Python commands, which is much easier than WinDbg built-in functions.

Comment: Great answer, but I strongly recommend using sosex if you plan to run `!gcroot` many times on a large memory dump. sosex can build a heap index which makes its reference-searching commands run much faster. http://www.stevestechspot.com/